# Animate circles with Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I Want to animate circles from one point created with Raphael JS.

Here is the code snippet I tried:

```
for(var i=1; i<4; i++) {
    var circle = paper.circle(width*0.4, height*0.2, 10*i);
    circle.attr(
        {
             stroke: '#0000d7',
             'stroke-width': 1,
             'stroke-linejoin': 'round'
        }
    );
    circle.animate({transform: "T0,100"}, 2000);
}
```

I animated the complete circle to walk. But I want that first the innermost circle then the second an then the third circle appears after some milliseconds (as an effect). But I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Do you want the animations to start at arbitrary times ? (in which case I would use setTimeout and call a function to animate it) Or after the previous animation has finished (in which case I would use the callback parameter in the animation).

Comment: I want that first the innermost circle appears. After it the second circle (e.g. after 1 second). Then the third circle.

Comment: If I animate: how to create an animation object (where to find a documentation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is going to be extendable to any number of circles, I would use setTimeout and a loop, similar to the one you were using.

To get the animation to work from a loop, you will have to use a 'closure', so that when the animation runs later, it will know which circle it is refering to (otherwise it may just animate the last object).

Using a function form of (function() {})() (called immediate mode), will make sure that variables are captured within function scope, so the variables are correct later.

```
for(var i=1; i<10; i++) {
    (function() {                    // start closure with functional scope
      var circle = paper.circle(width*0.4, height*0.2, 10*i);
      setTimeout( function() { circle.animate({transform: "T0,100"}, 2000); }, (i-1) * 2000  )
    })();
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ozaz2e/2/)

If you don't want all the circles at first, you still need a closure to capture the index i (which we will assign to c to make it clear in the function). Eg

```
for(var i=1; i<10; i++) {
    (function() {                   // start functional scope
      var c = i;                    // c is now tied to this scope
      setTimeout( function() { 
        var circle = paper.circle(width*0.4, height*0.2, 10*c);
        circle.animate({transform: "T0,100"}, 2000); 
      }, (c-1) * 2000  )
    })();
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ozaz2e/4/)

I'm not sure there's any need to create an animation object here, but if you wanted to, the docs are [here](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Raphael.animation)

Same example, but using a Raphael.animation.

```
var animation = Raphael.animation( {transform: "T0,100"}, 2000 )

for(var i=1; i<10; i++) {
    (function() {
      var c = i;
      setTimeout( function() { 
        var circle = paper.circle(width*0.4, height*0.2, 10*c);
        circle.animate( animation ); 
      }, (c-1) * 2000  )
    })();
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9ozaz2e/5/)